# Deploy a simple index.html to Azure with PowerShell

Tags: angularjs, powershell, azure

I want to deploy some simple html, js, css file to Azure (Web Site). 
Can't find any sample on how to do that with PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a simply one-size-fits-all PowerShell Cmdlet to deploy to Azure Websites.  You have a range of deployment models you can use (VSOnline, Git, FTP, et al) but no 'Update-AzureWebsite' that takes a deployable package of any variety. The [Websites documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/) provides a list of supported deployment methods.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've now got a working local Git deploy of my site.